# how to use window.open in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have injected an iframe in a webpage. In the iframe I have added a `window.open()`, like this:

```
window.open("mypage.com", "_self");
```

But this refreshes the iframe with *mypage.com*. The requirement is to load this page in the same main browser.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.open` if you want to *open a window*.

If you want to load a document into the current frame, then use `location = "http://example.com";`

If you want to load a document into the top level frame, then use `top.location = "http://example.com";`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://mypage.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
window.open("mypage.com", "_self");
```

To

```
window.open("mypage.com", "mypopupname");
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it opens in a new browser tab... I want the browser to refresh with that page